# What's the quickest way to generate Entity Framework model code given an SQLite database?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite, ef-database-first

I've got an SQLite database defined by an SQL DDL (CREATE TABLE etc.) script and am to derive Entity Framework model classes to work with it.

In the past, when I had an opportunity to try Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and Microsoft SQL Server in the same situation, Visual Studio allowed me to use "database-first" approach and reverse-engineer the model to create the model classes automatically. But I can't find anything like that available in Visual Studio 2015 Community and SQLite.

Am I missing something or are there, perhaps, 3-rd party tools that can do the job to set me free of mechanically typing all the model code manually?

Comment: EF6, I believe, @ErikEJ, I am not 100% sure what is EF Core to be honest, I use System.Data.Entity.DbContext to access the database from a WinForms application compiled against .Net Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Yes, that is entity framework 6, then -see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VS Express you are out of luck, since you cannot install DDEX providers or any other extensions using that edition. Use Community, the download sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.104.0.exe from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki (see my blogpost here for detailed info: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html )

If you use EF Core, upgrade to Community, and install the latest daily of my VS extension SQLite Toolbox, which has a feature to generate an EF Core Model via GUI https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Release-notes

Comment: That was a kind of typo, indeed I use the Community Edition actually, Not Express Edition.

Comment: BTW, why sqlite-netFx46-setup-BUNDLE-x86-2015-1.0.104.0.exe? The instructions on the download page say one should avoid the bundles (except of in legacy compatibility scenarios) and use non-bundle versions (sqlite-netFx46-setup-x86-2015-1.0.104.0.exe in this case) instead. I am also very curious about the x86 choice. I have damned everything while trying to make some kind of SQLite assemblies work on my Windows-64 PC (needless to say 99% of target computers will run 64-bit Windows too), the only thing that worked finally was the SQLite package from NuGet.

Comment: Did you read my blog post?? You need to DDEX provider, and that is only included in that package (read the BOLD instructions on the download page) - VS is a 32 bit app!

Comment: I've read it and it doesn't seem to work for me (SQLite won't appear in the "Change data source window"). Most probably this is because the latest SQLite version and the NuGet version don't match or something like that. I am going to give EFCore a try. Thank you for the detailed post, for the answer and for the inspiration to try EFCore.

Comment: @EricEJ I've switched to EF Core and used your great toolbox extension to generate the model code but now it won't insert new records into the DB. I have ended up using a dirty hack - using `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` to insert new records manually. Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547046/why-wont-entity-framework-core-save-a-new-record-to-an-sqlite-table-having-a-fo