# Why won't Entity Framework Core save a new record to an SQLite table having a foreign key?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have created a following simple SQLite database for experimenting purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE "cities" 
(
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  TEXT UNIQUE
);    

CREATE TABLE `people` 
(
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `city`  INTEGER,
    `name`  TEXT,
    `surname`   TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(`city`) REFERENCES `cities`(`id`)
);
```

Then I have used the [SQLite Toolbox](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Release-notes) by @erikej to generate the model code.

Right after that the following code works just fine:

```
var context = new SqliteEfcExampleContext();
var city = new Cities {Name = "Praha"};
context.Cities.Add(city);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This adds the city to the database immediately and this can be seen by an external client.

The following code, however, does nothing:

```
var context = new SqliteEfcExampleContext();
var city = context.Cities.Single(c => c.Name == "Praha"); // I know this is unsafe
var person = new People {Name = "Jan"};
city.People.Add(person);
context.People.Add(person);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Even simpler:

```
var context = new SqliteEfcExampleContext();
var person = new People { Name = "Jan" };
context.People.Add(person);
context.SaveChanges();
```

works neither. It seems that the mere existence of the foreign key column (even when it is nullable and is not used) makes it impossible to insert a record into the table.

Adding

```
context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Added
context.Update(person)
```

and

```
context.Dispose()
```

don't help.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE:

As soon as I have removed the properties used for the City and People entities to reference each other (to let them work as simple independent tables, the foreign key column is nullable anyway) adding cities has stopped working too.

Also, If I just add a city using `context.Cities.Add(city);` (calling `context.SaveChanges();` after that, but this does not seem to do anything at all in side effects) and try to get it by name later using the same context - it won't find it. I have also tried using `context.Local` instead of just `context`.

At the same time, `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` works just fine and lets me insert a record manually.

Comment: Why don't you use built-in EF for generating your model?

Comment: "built-in EF" doesn't offer to generate the a model given an SQLite DB, @dotNET

Comment: It certainly does. I have used it in multiple projects. You need to have SQLite provider installed though, but that's about it. EF works cleanly on top of SQLite provider, just like it does with SQL Server and other providers.

Comment: 1st of all it doesn't work "OOTB", there is job (http://erikej.blogspot.cz/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html) to be done  to make it work and it is not really straightforward: the DDEX provider version mis to match the version of the current SQLite EF6 NuGet package and the default latest versions don't seem to match. @dotNET

Comment: 2nd I just want to use EF Core to get acquainted with it.

Comment: What does "does nothing" mean? Are you looking at the correct database file? Check your file system for multiple copies of the db file..

Comment: @ErikEJ this has already came into my mind and I have multi-checked this already. Also `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT...` works and inserts the data into the correct file. Data added to the file manually (using DB Browser for SQLite) also get selected from the context successfully (and I don't forget to close DB Browser to release the database file lock).

Comment: I have even given up the database-first approach and tried code-first. It has created the database with all the tabless succesfully but still won't insert the data. Also, If I just add a city using `Context.Cities.Add(city);` and try to get it by name later using the same context - it won't find it.

Comment: Feel free to share a repro project with me (based on Database First, please)